# AFNetworking setUploadProgressBlock stops updating

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

Im my App there is a function to upload an image to a web server. While this is happening in the background I set up a progress bar so that the user can see the uploads status. I'm uploading the progress bar as shown below. Everything works fine as long an no other HTTP requests are made. As soon as another request is made setUploadProgressBlock stops updating but setCompletionBlockWithSuccess will eventually get called so my progress bar will be at some percentage between 30 and 70 but the upload has actually finished. For the other request I'm not using AFNetworking. There is an example below also. I've tried calling [operation waitUntillFinished] and a few other examples I've seen online but nothing seems to be working.

Image Upload =

```
NSData *postData= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"description=%@&location=%@&image=%@",i, l, d] dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/upload/create", SERVICE_URL]];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

        float percentDone = ((float)(totalBytesWritten) / (float)(totalBytesExpectedToWrite));

        [progressLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", (percentDone * 100)]];
        [progressView setProgress:percentDone];

}];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);

}
  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);

  }
 ];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

All other requests =

```
NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/add", SERVICE_URL]];

        NSData *postData= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@", user_id] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:loginURL];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {


         }];
```

**UPDATE:**

To explain a little more, here is an example of what the console will look like through this process -

Sent 437568 of 769069 bytes

Another API call sent

progress bar stops getting updated

Another API call response

success: Image upload response

Answer (score 1):

Your unowned HTTP client instance is probably being deallocated before the operation can finish. Use the static singleton pattern shown in the example, or store it in a `strong` property of some owning view controller.

Answer (score 0):

`setText:` and `setProgress` are called from a wrong thread, and not getting updated is the least harmful thing that may happen here.

Use either

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [progressLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", (percentDone * 100)]];
    [progressView setProgress:percentDone];
});
```

or

```
[progressLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", (percentDone * 100)] waitUntilDone:NO];
[progressView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgress:) withObject:(id)percentDone waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question. Didn't help at all. The progress bar updates fine until another request is called. If no other API call is made the progress bar will reach 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Switched over to ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to retrieve the upload progress and problem solved!